# how do I use isNaN to check if the input is number or not?

Tags: javascript

I want to restrict symbol, negative number and all other non relative stuff in my code. My professor tell me to use isNaN but I have no idea how to apply in my code. Can someone help me out with that? I have attached my code below

```
<!-- Network Latency Calculator -->

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Network Latency Calculation</title>
  <script>

     var firstNumber; // first string entered by user
     var secondNumber; // second string entered by user
 var thirdNumber; // third string entered by user
 var fourthNumber; // fourth string entered by user
     var number1; // first number to add
     var number2; // second number to add
 var number3; // third number to add
 var number4; // fourth number to add
     var sum; // sum of number1 and number2 and number3 and number4
 var sumresult;




     // read in first number from user as a string
     firstNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Propagation time  (no negative number, letter, blank space, and symbol is not allow)" );

     // read in second number from user as a string
    secondNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Transmission time  (no negative number, letter, blank space, and symbol is not allow)" );


 // read in third number from user as a string
     thirdNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Queuing time  (no negative number, letter, blank space, and symbol is not allow)" );


 // read in fourth number from user as a string
     fourthNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Propagation delay  (no negative number, letter, blank space, and symbol is not allow)" );








     // convert numbers from strings to integers
     number1 = parseFloat( firstNumber ); 
     number2 = parseFloat( secondNumber );
 number3 = parseFloat( thirdNumber );
 number4 = parseFloat( fourthNumber );

     sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4; // add the numbers

 sumresult = parseFloat( sum );


     // display the results
     document.writeln( "<h1>The network latency is " + sum + "</h1>" );
 document.writeln( "<p>Propagation time " + number1 + "</p>" );
 document.writeln( "<p>Transmission time " + number2 + "</p>" );
 document.writeln( "<p>Queuing time " + number3 + "</p>" );
 document.writeln( "<p>Propagation delay " + number4 + "</p>" );

 if ( sumresult < 1 )
        document.writeln( "<p>Network performance is good.</p>" );
 else ( document.writeln( "<p>Warning: Network performance needs improvement.</p>" ));






  </script>
</head><body></body>
```

Comment: `isNaN(whatever)` will be true if `whatever` is not a number - note: `isNaN("1.23")` will be false even though `"1.23"` is a string - so you'll still need to parse/coerce values to `Number` if you want to use them as such

Answer (score 0):

In a production web application you wouldn't prompt the user for numbers - you would display a form for the user to fill out.

But, since we're working with a toy application, you can simply repeat the prompt until the user gets it right:

```
function getNumberFromUser(promptText) {
    var n = NaN;
    while(isNaN(n) || (n < 0)) {
       var nString = window.prompt(promptText);
       n = parseFloat(nString);
    }
    return n;
}
 var number1 = getNumberFromUser("Enter the Propagation time  (no negative number, letter, blank space, and symbol is not allow)");
 var number2 = getNumberFromUser("Enter the Transmission time  (no negative number, letter, blank space, and symbol is not allow)");
 //etc
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but isn't your while statement going to repeat if they enter any positive number?

Comment: @jas7457 - Doh! It should be `<`, not `>=`. I'll fix it.

Comment: Should I add the code before the promt? because the webstie does not run.

Comment: maybe you should allow people to cancel the prompt too

Comment: my code is working now, but I get a quick question. How can I get a prompt to show "please enter a positive number?"

Comment: @JayHuang - I was happy to help, but I feel I've done enough for you now. Try and understand each line of this code, and then you should be able to change it to suit your needs.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I added "var error = getNumberFromUser("Please enter a postive number")" into your code. I can get the warning but it does not break the loop. How can I break the loop